# IndexedRDD used in streaming context?

Tags: join, apache-spark, indexedrdd

I want to use a fast join operation in Spark streaming context, such as A join B, A is a fixed dataset reading from file, B is a small streaming RDD read from socket. I've tried the common way provided by spark, 5,000,000 RDD joining 10 streaming RDD costs 4 seconds. Later I've tried using IndexedRDD, but I can't make it. I have following questions:

1. Is 4 seconds slow? Can I use some performance tuning method such as broadcast join to improve? If it is slow, why? I heard that RDD's join operation is linear search, is that true?
2. Can IndexedRDD's join operation faster than the common way?
3. How to use IndexedRDD in a streaming context? I've tried this way:

   ```
   streaming_rdd.transform{ rdd =>
                            indexed_data.innerJoin(IndexedRDD(rdd)){(id, a, b) => (a, b)}
   ```

   It pass the compile but when running I got the error:

   ```
   java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to [Lscala.Tuple2;
   ```

   I don't know if this is a proper way to use IndexedRDD, and I don't know what caused this error either. Can some one help me?

Comment: The project isn't really active and there seems to be an issue about it since a year without any response whatsoever. https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd/issues/13

Comment: @eliasah - Disappointing. Can you point to some way to update an RDD from within a stream? I realize asking for pointers to tools doesn't fit the SO question guidance, but I could use a lead. Spark itself indicates that the streams are immutable, but IndexedRDD seemed to have a way around that.

Comment: Hello Jiaqi Gao, Were you able to use the indexedrdd ?